# curl returning 301 error after migrating to https

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-301

We recently migrated to SSL, and the site works great with the exception of one function.  The function uses curl in the code below to execute an api located on the same server.
The url variable for this function is:
news.hubsdev.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_api&task=acymailing.listcreate
The $ch variable is - resource id='384' type='curl'

```
        $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name() . '=' . session_id());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

The response is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://news.hubsdev.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_api&amp;task=acymailing.listcreate">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

We are using PHP version 5.6 hosted on AWS.  I tested the ssl certificate and it passed with an "A".

How can I determine why I am getting this error?

Thanks!
Ken

Comment: If you add `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` it works? Also, add the `https://` in the url.

Comment: You are being redirected to the HTTPS version of your website

Comment: In other words, maybe your $url variable have http instead of https

Comment: i tried the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, and putting the https:// in the variable -still the same error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to follow the redirect using the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
```

From the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part
>   of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many
>   "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is
>   set).

Or you can simply use `https://` in your code to avoid the redirect.

Comment: Thank you, that worked!  I am assuming there is no potential unintended consequence, since it is all on the same server

Answer (score 0):

```
// conditions to send sms 

$data = array('username' => $username, 'apikey' => $apikey, 'numbers' => $mobile, "sender" => $sender, "message" => $msg);

if($this->sms_env == true)
{

    $ch = curl_init('https://api.textlocal.in/send?');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    $decoded_response = json_decode($response, true);

    curl_close($ch);

    $sms_status = @$decoded_response['status'];

    $status['sms'] = $sms_status;
}

$db_data = array(
    'sms_response'  => @$response,
    'unique_code'   => @$unique_code,
    'mobile_no'     => @$mobile,
    'message'       => @$msg,
    'username'      => $username,
    'apikey'        => $apikey,
    'sender_id'     => $sender
);

return $db_data;
```